# Git pull always results in a commit view. Not for coworkers

Tags: git

Everytime I pull, when there is something I need to get, I always get this message. Keep in mind there is nothing on my development branch that is new. I am just updating as others have put in commits.

```
Merge branch 'development' of github.com:blahblah/blah

# Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
# especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.
#
# Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts
# the commit.
~                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
~                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
~                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
~
```

When my coworkers run theirs, no. They saw it, from me, and said "that is odd...".

I tried:

```
git config --global --add merge.ff false
```

That didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any unpushed local commits? Have you tried `git pull --rebase`?

Comment: there is literally nothing on my base branch. I am just updating my out of syn branch to 'get the latest'. But it ALWAYS throws up that message.

Comment: Adding an additonal `merge.ff` set to `false` will merely exacerbate the situation. (You may have already set it to false.) I recommend never using `git pull` at all. Break it into its component commands: `git fetch` and then a second command of your choice, `git merge` or `git rebase`. You may want to check your global configuration (`git config --global --edit`) and remove any merge settings, and then do the same with your per-repository configuration (`git config --edit`). (Avoiding `git pull` is just a recommendation, not part of fixing the configuration.)

Answer (score 0):

`git pull` is actually merging your branch with another branch (in a nutshell `git pull` is  `git fetch` + `git merge`). That's how git works. Try to pull before commiting, or use `git rebase` instead.

Comment: But there is NOTHING in my base branch that is new. That is the issue. It is always pulling up that message. My coworkers do NOT get this message.

Comment: are you trying to pull from a different branch?

Comment: nope, I am in development.. and pulling from development. I am curious if my origin is not the same